# Arithmetic Operations in Arrays with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$data1 = array()
$data1 = array( '10','22','30')
```

and also another array carries

```
$data2 = array()
$data2 = array( '2','11','3');
```

I need to divide these two arrays(ie,$data1/$data2) and store value to $data3[].
I need to get it as follows

```
$data3[] = array('5','2','10')
```

If someone knows of an easy way to do this would be of great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that with a simple foreach statement:

```
$data1 = array('10','22','30')
$data2 = array('2','11','3');
$data3 = array();

foreach($data1 as $key => $value) {
    $data3[$key] = $value / $data2[$key];
}
```

Alternatively you can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
function divide($a, $b) {
    return $a / $b;
}

$data3 = array_map("divide", $data1, $data2);
```

And as of PHP 5.3 you can even use a lambda function to compress that to one row:

```
$data3 = array_map(function($a, $b) { return $a / $b; }, $data1, $data2);
```